# Integrating JOSSO with spring ws client

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-ws, spring-integration, josso

I am working on integrating a web service application with JOSSO framework for authentication . When ever a request comes for the service it should be authenticated first against an Active
Directory , and if it succeeds it should hit the endpoint . I could not find any relevant site for reference on the internet . Can some one please help me understand how this can be done ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using josso web services.
 Please find the below link for wsdl file. You can create a client to validate the user credentials against Active Directory or LDAP.

[JOSSO WEB SERVICES WSDL LINK](http://www.josso.org/wsdl/josso-1.2/josso-1.2.wsdl)

You can find the same from source code also:
 \josso-1.8.3-src\components\josso-ws-v1_2\src\main\wsdl\josso-1.2.wsdl

Just for testing, you can download this wsdl as a project in to sopa-uo tool and hit to get response.